# How to know whether a vector is a row or a column?

Tags: notation

When the text simply says that $X_i$ is a J-dimensional random variable, how do I know that it's supposed to have $1 \times j$ or $j \times 1$ dimension?

An example where this matters is Cramer-Wald device, taken from my professor's notes:

> Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a sample of J-dimensional random variables
>   and let $X$ be a J-dimensional random variable. Then, $X_n
>  \xrightarrow d X \iff \lambda'X_n \xrightarrow{d} \lambda'X,
>  \forall\lambda \in R^J $

I am taught that the $\Leftarrow$ direction of this device is used to prove multivariate convergence based on univariate convergence. Thus, I am able to infer that $\lambda'X_n \in R$, i.e. $(1 \times j)(j \times 1)$.

But is there a way to tell the dimension of $X_n$ based solely on notation, without context?

Comment: Without context nor convention, I don't think we can guess. Usually one consider vector columns.

Comment: Is my guess in the case of the Cramer-Wald device correct though? I just wonder had I not known the purpose of the Cramer-Wald, how could I know that $\lambda' X_N$ is $(1 \times 1)$ instead of $(j \times j)$

Comment: Sometimes you must infer from context. Usually the intent is obvious, even if never explicitly stated.

Comment: No, it is not. Authors usually clarify what they mean ("let $J$ be a _column_ vector ..." or "...a _row_ vector..." the first time the notation appears, and then you have to remember it. They usually keep it consistent for other vectors in the paper. So if $J$ without a prime is declared as a column vector, then any other vector appearing later with a prime is to be considered as a row vector. In books, there is usually a part in the beginning or at the end where symbols used repeatedly are defined, and then no clarifications are offered in the main text.

Comment: Okay, so what I glean from this discussion is that ideally authors should clarify, but they sometimes don't. Could anyone confirm whether my thinking in the case of the Cramer-Wald correct though?

Comment: By default, most mathematicians consider a "vector" to be a column vector so that matrices operate from the left. Regardless, the context usually suffices to tell.  In this case, interpreting $X$ as a row vector makes the statement utterly trivial (a test for convergence of $J$ values is replaced by a test for convergence of $J^2$ values, which subsumes as special cases the original $J$ tests), whereas interpreting it as a column vector gives it some content.